# How to display location of many events on one map

Tags: civievent, drupal-views, map

I want to display a map showing many events location.
I use Civicrm with Drupal 7.
I think that it's possible to get events location in Views, but I don't know how to do this.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Event location fields in to a View (assuming this is an Event based view) but you then need a mapping solution and whereas in the past I would have recommended [Open Layers](https://www.drupal.org/project/openlayers) there has been some disruption to that as a solution with the loss of access to certain map layer providers.